# Delegate method is not called in a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, google-signin

This is a wrapper class I've made for google login.

```
class GoogleLoginWrapper:NSObject, GIDSignInDelegate {

weak var presentingController:UIViewController!

init(presentingController:UIViewController) {
    super.init()
    self.presentingController = presentingController
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}

 // Google Delegate Methods  
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

   }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
   }
}
```

And I'm calling this class from a view controller class as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,GIDSignInUIDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         let googleWrapper = GoogleLoginWrapper(presentingController: self)
    }

    //IBAction method to call google login.

}
```

This opens the google authentication on safari but the problem is the delegate method is never called in GoogleLoginWrapper class. But if I put the same code defined in GoogleLoginWrapper in Appdelegate, it works. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your instance of `GoogleLoginWrapper` goes out of scope at the end of your `viewDidLoad` method so it is deallocated immediately. You can't call the `sign...` function with the code you posted.

You should use a property instead of a local variable to keep a reference to the `GoogleLoginWrapper` instance.

Comment: I thought the same thing, so I did something like above. Please check the updated code. It doesn't work.

Comment: That change doesn't fix anything. You need to keep the reference to `GoogleLoginWrapper` in your `ViewController` class. Your change is backwards and the weak reference doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: And an implicitly unwrapped weak reference is just asking for trouble.